# Expected value over many trials

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am a poker player and was talking to my friend about expected value. He claimed that if you play far enough above your bankroll, expected value can be negative, even if you have a skill edge. I responded that while your variance would certainly increase, there's no way that a +ev proposition can become -ev purely due to variance. He gave the following example: Say you start with 10 dollars, and play someone heads up (one on one) where the winner takes all of the money. Assume you are a better player and have a 51% chance of winning. 1) What is the expected value for n trials of this game(should then be trivial to show this function is always positive)? 2)What is the distribution of results?(i.e how frequently do we get to 0 dollars for a given number of trials, how frequently do we get other numbers, etc.)? And 3) Either a proof that my friend is wrong(which I think is definitely the case) or an example of a situation where one trial of a game is positive EV but there exists a number of trials where your ev is negative. Thanks

1) So clearly EV is positive and is trivial to calculate for one trial. It seems as though it should just be (.2)*n  where n is the number of trials. If we were to run an infinite number of trials, .2n clearly diverges so it seems our ev is infinite. I guess the point is that despite ending up with 0 dollars the vast majority of the time, occasionally you'd end up with an infinite amount of money, and this would make up for all of the times you hit 0.
2)So my approach is to look at how often we hit 0 dollars. We make a series of probabilities where the even terms are all 0 and the odd terms are some function of x and (1-x) where x is the probability we lose. So we have x, 0, x^2(1-x), 0, (1-x)(x)(1-x)(x)(x)+ (1-x)(1-x)(x)(x)(x) = 2[x^3+(1-x)^2], 0, … so it can be written in terms of number of paths to get to 0, where W is a win and L is a loss, which would be L, 0, WLL, 0, WLWLL and WWLLL, 0, WL(followed by our 5 letter sequences) and WWWLLLL and WWLWLLL and WWLLWLL so its just a problem in terms of number of paths where we have the condition that you start with a W, have one more L than W, we end with an LL sequence, and L<=W until the last L. so we only get to choose the middle n-3 terms in these sequences and in that middle n-3 terms number of W= number of L and L <=W+1 at all points

Comment: oh also I just remembered that the expected value function is linear so if its positive for one trial and more positive for a second trial, maybe yo can show that it will never cross 0 or something

Comment: Suppose you have $\$1000$. When you play for $\$500$ each time, and you can win $\$1$ (I know this is not the case, but it illustrates what may be the problem) or lose $\$500$, maybe you lose all your money before making any reasonable profit, making the expected value negative.

Comment: @ragnar the point is tat I'm dealing with a proposition that is +ev for one trial and want to know if there exists a number of trials for which its not positive. i agrees that there exist situations that are -ev if that's your point. maybe I'm just not understangg your post probably

Comment: It is right that when a single game has a positive expected value, playing that game $n$ ($n\in \mathbb N$) times also has a positive expected value. I think you'll need to ask your fried for some more explanation, because I can't think of one and don't see why in that case the EV would become negative.

Answer (score 0):

@Richard;

I do not think your friend is correct. If you were a 51 - 49 favorite such as having a coin that came up heads 51% of the time and your opponent wished to bet 1 dollar per flip on tails you would have a plus expectation of 2 cents per flip because after 100 flips you would expect to be up 2 dollars. If you flip 400 times you would expect to be up 8 dollars. How you actually do has nothing to do with your expectation. You could be down 50 dollars after 400 flips but you still have the best of it, a positive expectation.

It is true that betting a large percentage of your bankroll will produce big fluctuations. That is why limit games are safer than no limit games when you are trying to protect a small bankroll. That is how I understand it.